# how to call fun from another class in xml OnClick attribute

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

i need to run testPrint from NavbarActions.kt

```
class NavbarActions {

    fun testPrint(view: View) {
        Log.i("check", "success")
    }
    
}
```

from activity_navbar.xml without using NavbarActivity.kt in TW

```
<TextView
    android:onClick="?????"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TEST"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a custom binding adapter. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a file named `BindingAdapters.kt` (if it doesn't exist) in your project's source directory and add the following code:

```kotlin
import android.view.View
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter

@BindingAdapter("onClickTestPrint")
fun View.setTestPrintClickListener(navbarActions: NavbarActions) {
    setOnClickListener { navbarActions.testPrint(this) }
}
```

2. In your `activity_navbar.xml`, add the `onClickTestPrint` attribute to the `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TEST"
    app:onClickTestPrint="@{navbarActions}" />
```

Note that you need to replace `@{navbarActions}` with the actual instance of `NavbarActions` that you want to use.

3. Finally, when you set up the data binding in your activity (e.g., `MainActivity.kt`), make sure to set the `navbarActions` variable with an instance of `NavbarActions`:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.yourpackage.databinding.ActivityNavbarBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityNavbarBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_navbar)
        binding.navbarActions = NavbarActions()
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace `com.yourpackage` with the actual package name of your project.

Now, when the "TEST" TextView is clicked, it will directly call the `testPrint` function from the `NavbarActions` instance specified in the `navbarActions` variable in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `onClick` attribute will only translate to a function in the `Activity` that it's in. You will need to call the other function from the activity.